# NuGet package reference caused new folders in the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have project "A" with project folders "Folder1" and "Folder2".
I have put this project to the NuGet repo.
I have project "B" that needs to use project "A" via Nuget.

In the project "B" I have added a NuGet reference to "A". When Visual Studio has completed downloading and attaching library, the folders "Folder1" and "Folder2" for some reason has appeared in the "B".

Q1: why so?
Q2: how can I make "B" work without those folders? Just deleting is not a solution, I will need to periodically update both "A" and "B".

Comment: `the folders "Folder1" and "Folder2" for some reason has appeared in the "B".` Please try again with completely new projects and see if this behavior is consistent, and its not a random reason. because then there is no answer to your first question.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Unfortunaly I can't re-create and re-upload project "A" to NuGet, this is under a different account, but when I created a brand new empty "B" project and only added a NuGet ref then I had those new folders again.

Comment: Clearly whatever you specified in the NuGet get applied to your "project B". Without actually seeing your NuGet's manifest file at least there is no way to know what exactly you did to get folders included (but it is very common for NuGets to bring in source files into projects)

Comment: Could you please share your .nuspec file here? So that I can check the reason why folder add to the project. Are those two folder are just two common folders? And is it as content in the nuget package? You can hide your personal information in the .nuspec file.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT this was not me who uploaded this package to NuGet and I dont have that file... Do you think if package had content files included then this is the reason why folders appear in the project itself?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT we are ignoring this problem for now because we do not have access to the .nuspec file which is made by a different company

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka, Got it. Hope my answer help you understand the reason for this issue, even if you can't change it now. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<Content>` tag where you included your files, set `CopyToOutputPath` to false.

```
<Content Include="Folder1;Folder2">
    <CopyToOutputPath>false</CopyToOutputPath>
</Content>
```

This will include the folders in the NuGet package, but will not copy them to the root of the second project (B in your case).

Answer (score 0):

> NuGet package reference caused new folders in the project

According to your description, you may set the target folder as `content` in your `.nuspec` file for "Folder1" and "Folder2".

Based on the [convention-based working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#creating-the-nuspec-file), file in the contents are copied to the project root:

[image]

The `.nuspec` file like:

```
<files>
    <file src="xxx\Folder1" target="content\Folder1" />
</files>
```

To resolve this issue, you can change the target folder to other folder, like `Tools` folder.

Hope this helps.